# On the existence of an element of a group whose order is the LCM of orders of given two elements which commute

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

I came up with the following proposition.

**Proposition**
Let $G$ be a group.
Let $x, y$ be elements of finite order in $G$ such that $xy = yx$.
Let $n$ be the order of $x$.
Let $m$ be the order of $y$.
Let $l =$ lcm$(n, m)$.
Then there exists an element of order $l$ in $G$.

**Outline of my proof**
There exist a divisor $a$ of $n$ and a divisor $b$ of $m$ such that gcd$(a, b) = 1$ and $l = ab$.
There exist $x, y \in G$ whose orders are $a, b$ respectively.
Then $z = xy$ is of order $l$.

**My question**
How do you prove the proposition?
I would like to know other proofs based on different ideas from mine.
I welcome you to provide as many different proofs as possible.

Comment: what is the order of xy in this problem?

Comment: I would like to point out the following policy of StackExchange because it doesn't seem to be well-known and some users seem to dislike a question to which the poster already knows the answer.
`[It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! ? phrase it in the form of a question.
To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.]`
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Let $\circ(xy) = s$. Since $(xy)^l =e$, we have $s \mid l$. Now $(xy)^s = e$, implies $x^sy^s =e$ and therefore $x^s=y^{-s}$. Now $x^{sn}=e$ and $y^{sm}=e$ which yield $m \mid ns$ and $n\mid sm$. Since $gcd(m,n)=1$, we have $m\mid s$ and $n\mid s$ and thus $mn=lcm(m,n)=s$.

Now we assume that $m$ and $n$ are not relatively prime. We write $l=p^{r1}_{1}⋯p^{rs}_{s}$, $p_i$ are primes and $ri \geq 1$. Using part 1, it is enough to show that for each $i$, there is an element of order $p^{ri}_{i}$.  Note that $p^{ri}_{i}$ divides either $m$ or $n$. Thus $y^{m/p^{ri}_{i}}$ or $x^{n/p^{ri}_{i}}$ (whichever one divides evenly) has order $p^{ri}_{i}$. Therefore we have shown that an element of order $l$, the least common multiple of $m$ and $n$, is in $G$.

Comment: I don't understand the latter part. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MakotoKato: I have rewritten the proof. I think this is better.

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: @GA316 Thank you for your comment.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

can you prove that if $x$ has order $m$ ,$y$ has order $n$ and $xy=yx$ then order of $xy$ is $lcm(m,n)$ if $gcd (m,n) =1$.

Comment: No, I can't. Can you?

Comment: let $l=lcm(m,n)$, prove that $(xy)^l = e$ and by using the definition of lcm prove that $l$ is least numbet satisfying this.