# Why is the multiplicative group of a finite field cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Why is the multiplicative group $(K\smallsetminus\{0\},\cdot)$ of a finite field $(K,+,\cdot)$ always cyclic?

Comment: [This](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic) might help.

Comment: In most cases, if you’re asking the question of why something is true, well, that’s the whole point of mathematics, and you should try to find a proof. If you can’t understand the proof (happens to all of us!), then you might ask here for help with understanding.

Comment: In general, it sounds better to ask "How do you prove Result X?" rather than ask "Why is Result X true?" They sort of mean the same thing but the first one is much clearer :)

Comment: Keith Conrad has collected six proofs of this theorem for the field $\mathbb Z/p$ at http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicFp.pdf.

Comment: To @MartinBrandenburg who marked this as duplicate, I don't think so, for two reasons: 1) I'm asking about the whole group, not finite subgroups, and 2) I'm asking about a finite field, whereas the question this question has been marked as possible duplicate of asks about the subgroups of a generic field's multiplicative group.

Comment: @lhf the link now has 7 proofs, not 6, and the URL has changed to http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf.

Comment: I have to prove this statement using the fact that any Abelian
group is a module over $\mathbb{Z}$. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In a field, $X^d-1$ can have at most $d$ roots, so there can always be at most $d$ elements whose order divides $d$.

The only commutative finite groups with this property are the cyclic groups.

If $G$ is any other commutative finite group then it has a subgroup of the form $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z)^2$ for some integer $p$, which means it has $p^2$ elements of order dividing $p$.

Comment: That argument depends on the structure of abelian groups.

Comment: Uh-huh. And how do you prove that «the only commutative finite groups with this property are the cyclic groups»?

Comment: @MickG : as lhf pointed out, I rely on the structure theorem of finite commutative groups. For such a group $G$ there is a sequence of integers $(d_i)$ where $d_i$ divides $d_{i+1}$ such that $G = \oplus \Bbb Z/d_i \Bbb Z$. In the case of noncyclic groups this sequence has more than $1$ element so it has a subgroup of the form $(\Bbb Z/d_1 \Bbb Z)^2$

Comment: @MickG: There is also more elementary reason for this. Firstly oberve that analyzing the structure of a cyclic finite group of order $n$ yields the Euler's formula $\sum_{d \mid n}\varphi(d)=n$, where $\varphi$ is the [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function). Now, if  a finite group $G$ has at most $d$ elements with order dividing $d$ for every $d$ dividing $|G|$, then using Euler's formula one can see that it necessarily has an element of order $|G|$.

Comment: @Pavel Coupek, I am not understanding your argument for existence of an element of order |G|.

Comment: @Martund Let me say it a bit differently: A cyclic group of some order $m$ has precisely $\varphi(k)$ elements of order $k$ for every divisor $k$ of $m$, which also proves the Euler's formula. Now if $g \in G$ is of order $d$, then $\langle g \rangle$ consists of $d$ elements of order dividing $d$, so it contains all such elements of $G$ by assumption. In particular, $\langle g \rangle$ is the unique cyclic subgroup of $G$ of order $d$, and in particular, $G$ has in this case $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$. So $G$ has at most $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ (either $0$ or $\varphi(d)$).

Comment: @Martund Now, if $G$ did not have an element of order $n$, it would have at most $\sum_{d \mid n, d \neq n}\varphi(d) <\sum_{d \mid n}\varphi(d)=n$ elements, contradiction.

Answer (score 41):

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of a finite field, $n$ its order.
Let $d$ be a divisor of $n$, $\psi(d)$ the number of elements order $d$ in $G$.
Suppose there exists an element $a$ of $G$ whose order is $d$.
Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$.
Then every element of $H$ satisfies the equation $x^d = 1$.
Since the number of the solutions of $x^d = 1$ is less than or equal to $d$
and the order of $H$ is $d$, $H = \{x \in G\mid x^d = 1\}$.
Therefore $\psi(d) = 0$ or $\phi(d)$, where $\phi(d)$ is the Euler's function, i.e. the number of elements of order $d$ of a cyclic group of order $d$.
Since $\sum_{d\mid n} \psi(d) = n = \sum_{d\mid n} \phi(d)$, $\psi(d) = \phi(d)$ for all $d\mid n$.
In particular $\psi(n) = \phi(n)$, which means there exists an element of order $n$ in $G$.
This completes the proof.

Comment: You say that the number of solutions for $x^d=1$ is less than or equal to $d$. Is this because we can think of $x^d=1$ as being a polynomial in $F[x]$: $x^d-1=0\in F[x]$ and thus the number of distinct roots must be less than or equal to the degree?

Comment: @Grifball Yes, that's exactly why.

Answer (score 10):

Let $G$ be the multiplicative group of a finite field, $n$ its order.
Let $x$ be an element of $G$, $d$ its order.
Let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$.
If $G = H$, we are done.
Suppose otherwise.
There exists $y \in G - H$.
Let $m$ be the order of $y$, $l$ = lcm$(d, m)$.
Suppose $d = l$.
Then $m\mid d$.
Hence $y^d = 1$.
This contradicts the fact that the number of solutions of the equation $X^d = 1$ is less than or equal to $d$.
Hence $d \lt l$.
By the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555181/on-the-existentence-of-an-element-of-a-group-whose-order-is-the-lcm-of-orders-of), there exists an element $z$ of order $l$ in $G$.
We can repeat this process until we find a generator of $G$.
This completes the proof.