# Algebra notation $\mathbb{F}^*_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

*Let p be a prime number which is odd.*

*(a) Show that $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ has a unique subgroup of order $(p - 1)/2$, namely the subgroup consisting of squares of elements of $\mathbb{F}^*_p$.*

My question is basic: what does $\mathbb{F}^*_p$ refers to ?

Comment: The multiplicative group of the finite field, i.e., without zero (which cannot be invertible). The group $(\mathbb{F}_p^{\times},\cdot)$ has $p-1$ elements and is cyclic, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837562/why-is-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-finite-field-cyclic).

Comment: This is an answer to the question, give it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the set of all non-zero elements in the field of $p$ elements.  Typically $R^*$ is the set of units in $R$ but since $\mathbb F_p$ is a field, any non-zero element is a unit.  The set of units is actually a group with respect to multiplication (assuming $R$ has an identity).  In the case of $\mathbb F_p$ this group is just $\mathbb Z/(p-1)\mathbb Z$.