# Element order is not a divisor

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I have field $\mathbb F_2 [\alpha]$, where $\alpha^{6} = \alpha^4 +\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1$. As I know, this is field, because $p(x)=x^6+x^4+x^3+x+1$ irreducible polynomial (if ain't wrong). So, i need to find ord($\alpha$). As I know, possible ord($\alpha$) = {1, 3, 7, 9, 21, 61}, because this numbers are dividers of |$\mathbb F_2[\alpha]^{*}$| = 63.

But ord($\alpha$)=20, which is not dividers 63.

Could it be?

Computing:
$\alpha^{6} = \alpha^4 +\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1$ => $\alpha^{9} = \alpha^{6} \cdot \alpha^{3} = \alpha^{3} \cdot (\alpha^4 +\alpha^3 + \alpha + 1) = \alpha^5 +\alpha^4 + \alpha^2 + 1 $

$\alpha^7 = \alpha^5 + \alpha^4 + \alpha^2 + \alpha$

$\alpha^8 = \alpha^7 \alpha = \alpha^6 + \alpha^5 +\alpha^3 + \alpha = \alpha^5 + \alpha^4 + 1$

$\alpha^{10} = \alpha^9 \alpha = \alpha^5 + \alpha^4 +1$

$\alpha^{20} = (\alpha^{10})^2 = \alpha^{10} + \alpha^8 + 1 = \alpha^5 + \alpha^4 +1 + \alpha^5 + \alpha^4 +1 + 1 = 1$

Comment: Have you got a typo? $\alpha$ is not a root of $p(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
p(x)=x^6-x^4-x^3-x-1=(x^3 + x^2 + 2x + 1)(x^2 + 1)(x + 2)
$$
with $p(\alpha)=0$, so it is not irreducible over $\Bbb F_3$.

Edit: Over $\Bbb F_2$ it is indeed irreducible. Then see for example this related post:
[Factoring $x^6 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297568/factoring-x6-x4-x3-x-1-over-mathbbf-16/2297857#2297857)

How did you compute the order of $\alpha$? My calculations are different (let me write $a$ for $\alpha$):
\begin{align*}
a^7 & = a^5+a^4+a^2+a,\\
a^8 & = a^5+a^4+a^2+a+1,\\
a^9 & = a^5+a^4+a^2+1,\\
a^{10} & = a^5+a^4+1,\\
a^{11} & = a^5 + a^4 + a^3 + 1,\\
a^{20} & = a^2+a+1,\\
a^{21} & = a^3+a^2+a,\\
a^{63} & = 1.
\end{align*}
So the order is $63$, and the problem has dissolved.

Comment: Nor is the order of any of the roots $20$. (!)

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. Field F_2

Comment: I wrote finding order in computing, but I was surprised that a^8=a^10

Comment: I undestood!
So, if other orders did not fit, then it can be argued that the remaining one is it?

Comment: As you said, the order is a divisor of $63$, and if $1,3,7,21$ do not work, then it must be $63$ itself. You have a typo in your list of orders, $61$ is impossible.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!