# Show that the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm looking for a proof of this that does not rely on the Chinese remainder theorem, since the exercise is from a book that has not reached such a point (Aluffi, Algebra).

Show that for $p$ prime, the multiplicative group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is cyclic. You may use that for $p$ prime, the equation $x^d=1$ has at most $d$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. (hint: for $g\in G$ of maximal order, $\forall h\in G, |h|\;|\;|g|$, and in particular, $h^{|g|}=1$.)

My only idea for now is constructing an element $a\in G$ such that $|a|=|G|$, using the fact that a group of order $n$ is cyclic $\iff\exists$ an element of order $n$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/837562/660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the structure theorem for finite Abelian groups, you will
be able to prove that either a finite Abelian group $G$ is cyclic,
or that its exponent is $<|G|$, that is there is $m<|G|$
with $g^m=e$ for for all $g\in G$.

An alternative attack: show that for $d\mid (p-1)$ the group
$G=(\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z)^*$ has exactly $d$ solutions of $x^d\equiv1$.
If you compare $G$ to $H=\Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$, you find that
the number of elements of order dividing $d$ is the same in each,
therefore the number of elements of order exactly $d$ is the
same in each, and now take $d=p-1$.

Comment: The question specifically asked for a proof that did not use the structure theorem for f.g. abelian groups (but it has been edited out after G. Sassatelli's comment).

Comment: Note that the alternative attack should be approached by induction on $d$.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more your alternative attack? How can I find the number of elements of order dividing $d$?

Comment: @George There are $\le (p-1)/d$ solutions of $x^{(p-1)/d}\equiv1$, so $\ge d$ different values of $y^{(p-1)/d}$ modulo $p$, each of which solves $y^d\equiv1$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Use the hint.

Among all elements if $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, let $g$ have maximal order, $d$. If we assume that $d<p-1$, then  there exists $h\in (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ that is *not* among the $d$ solutions of $x^d=1$. The order $m$ of $h$ is thus not a divisor of $d$.
Let $h'=h^{m/\gcd(m,d)}$. Then $h'$ is of order $m'=\frac m{\gcd(m,d)}$, which is coprime to $d$. Conclude that $hg$ has order $m'd>d$, contradiction.

Comment: Shouldn't $hg$ be $h'g$?

Comment: $m'$ might not be coprime with $d$, for instance $m=8$, $d=6$.

Comment: Isn't it enough that the order of $h$ does not divide $d$? ie: We know clearly that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a finite group, so the orders of all its elements is finite. If $g$ has maximal order $d$, and $d<p-1$, then $\exists h$ such that $h^d\neq 1$. But then $|h|$ does not divide $d$, and hence since it is a finite group, we get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d\leq p-1$ be the maximal order. Now since the order of an element in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$ divides $d$ there are $p-1$ solutions of $x^d=[1]$. So we have $p-1\leq d$, and $d=p-1$.