# A proof attempt of the cyclicity of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups, automorphism-group

Let $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ be the multiplicative group of the integers modulo $p$, for $p$ a prime. It is well known that this group is cyclic (for a survey of the many proofs so far, see [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf)). I'm trying with this other proof attempt, but (as long as everything is okay till there, which I'm unsure about) I'm stuck in the final step.

---

In the following, I'll assume as known the result $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)\cong(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$.

All the nontrivial elements of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ (the additive group of the integers modulo $p$) have order $p$. Automorphisms preserve the order of the elements, and hence every $\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ permutes the nontrivial elements of  $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, namely:
$$\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)\Longrightarrow \begin{cases}
\psi(0) = 0 \\
\psi(i) = \sigma(i), \text{ for all }i=1,\dots,p-1 \\
\tag 1
\end{cases}$$
for some $\sigma\in S_{p-1}$. By the linearity of $\psi$, the permutation $\sigma$ in $(1)$ fulfils the condition:
$$\sigma(k)\equiv\sigma(1)k\pmod p\tag 2$$
Every choice of $\sigma(1)$ gives rise to a distinct element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$; in particular, the identity of $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$ corresponds to $\sigma(1)=1$, and if $\sigma(1)\ne 1$, then $\sigma$ moves all the $p-1$ nontrivial elements of $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$. Therefore, $\sigma\in S_{p-1}$ in $(1)$ is of the form (cycles in comma-notation):
$$\small{\bigl(1,\sigma(1),\sigma(1)^2,\dots,\sigma(1)^{l-1}\bigr)\bigl(j_2,\sigma(1)j_2,\sigma(1)^2j_2,\dots,\sigma(1)^{l-1}j_2\bigr)\dots\bigl(j_r,\sigma(1)j_r,\sigma(1)^2j_r,\dots,\sigma(1)^{l-1}j_r\bigr)}\tag 3$$
for some $1\le r\le p-1$, where:
$$1+\sigma(1)+\sigma(1)^2+\dots+\sigma(1)^{l-1}\equiv 0\pmod p\tag 4$$
and:
$$lr=p-1\tag 5$$
The case $r=p-1$ corresponds to the trivial permutation/automorphism. For $r<p-1$, conditions $(4)$ and $(5)$ come from being $\sigma$ a fixed point-free permutation, and in turn they imply that there are at most $l_r-1=\frac{p-1}{r}-1$ automorphisms of order $l_r:=\frac{p-1}{r}$.

Now, $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)$($\cong(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$) is a finite Abelian group; so, if $n$ is the maximal order among the elements
in the group, then the order of every element divides $n$. Let $l_r$ be the maximal order, for some $r\ge1$, and $\{1,d_2,\dots,d_{D_r}\}$ the set of the proper divisors of $l_r$. Then, from $(4)$, an upper bound to the number of automorphisms is given by:
\begin{alignat}{1}
m_r &= \underbrace{l_r-1}_{\text{max num. aut. order }l_r}+\underbrace{\frac{l_r}{d_2}-1}_{\text{max num. aut. order }l_r/d_2}+\space\dots\space+\underbrace{\frac{l_r}{d_{D_r}}-1}_{\text{max num. aut. order }l_r/d_{D_r}}+1 \\
\tag 6
\end{alignat}
where the final "$+1$" accounts for the trivial automorphism. From $(6)$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
m_r &= \frac{l_r}{1}+\frac{l_r}{d_2}+\dots+\frac{l_r}{d_{D_r}}+\frac{l_r}{l_r}-D_r \\
&= \frac{l_r}{1}+\frac{l_r}{d_2}+\dots+\frac{l_r}{d_{D_r}}+\frac{l_r}{l_r}-(D_r+1)+1 \\
&= \text{sum of the divisors of }l_r-\text{number of the divisors of }l_r\space+\space 1 \\
\tag 7
\end{alignat}
For $p$ such that $q:=\frac{p-1}{2}$ is prime, the maximal order $l_r$ is either $l_1=p-1$, or $l_2=q$, or $l_q=2$. In the latter two cases, $(7)$ yields, respectively:
\begin{alignat}{2}
m_2 &= q+1-2+1=q &&<p-1 \\
m_q &= 3-2+1=2 &&<p-1, \text{ as soon as }p>3 \\
\tag 8
\end{alignat}
which both contradict the fact that there are $p-1$ automorphisms. Therefore, there must be some automorphism of (maximal) order $p-1$, and hence $(\Bbb Z/(2q+1)\Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic for every prime $q$ such that $2q+1$ is prime either, such as: $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/47\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/59\Bbb Z)^\times$, $(\Bbb Z/83\Bbb Z)^\times$, *etc.*

Likewise, if $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is composite, I think I should use $(7)$ to firstly prove that $r>2\Rightarrow m_2>m_r$, and then that $m_2<p-1$. This is where I'm stuck. (But it's far more probable that the upper bound $(7)$ is simply too weak to prove the cyclicity of $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$ for $p$'s different from those already accounted for here above.)

Comment: Another (shorter) proof is, that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837562/why-is-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-finite-field-cyclic). So for $\Bbb F_p$ this gives that $(\Bbb Z/p)^{\times}$ is cyclic. This is on page $5$ of Conrad's note you have linked above. It is [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic).

Comment: Well your aproach is very simmilar to the standard aproach for proving cyclicity ,but your estimates for the number of automorphism of order $l$ is far from sharp, and so it does not have any chance of sucsess. you obtain this estimate from $4$, but if $l$ is composite, then $x^l+x^{l-1}+...+1$ is not ireducible, in other word of $\gamma$ has order $2k$, then $\gamma^k$ has order $2$ not $2k$.

Comment: but if you think more you can give the exact number of automorphism of order $l$ (spoiler alert:the answer is $\phi(l)$) and then you get something simmilar to 7, which need a little work to prove the theorem.

Comment: @ali, do you mean that $\sum_{d\mid l_{max}}\phi(l_{max}/d)<p-1$ for $l_{max}<p-1$? Why?

Comment: yes in fact we have $\sum_{d\mid l_{max}}\phi(l_{max}/d)=l_{max}$! you can prove this by induction on the number of primes dividing $l_{max}$, you can also prove this by noting that every $n\le l_{max}$ can written in a unique way as $n=dm$ where $d|l$ and $(m,l/d)=1$

Comment: in fact this also shows that you don't have room for eror in your estimates

Comment: @ali. Thanks for your time. Now I see that this is actually the proof #1 of the resource linked in my post.