# Help with Problem in Abstract Algebra

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and $O_K$ its ring of integers. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $O_K$. Prove that $G = \{a+P \mid a \in O_K, a \not\in P\}$ is a cyclic group with respect to multiplication. What is the order of $G$?

I have been stuck on this problem for some time now. Proving that $G$ is a group was fairly straightforward but I am unsure how to prove that it is cyclic. This problem was in the Norms of Ideals chapter in my book but I am not sure how to apply concepts learned from that chapter for this problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't $G$ equal to the group of units in $O_K/P = k(P)$? The fact that [such a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837562/why-is-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-finite-field-cyclic) is known to be cyclic when $k(P)$ is finite might help.

Comment: Since $P$ is prime ideal, $O_K/P$ is a finite field and hence $(O_K/P)^{*}$ forms a cyclic group with respect to multiplication

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837562/why-is-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-finite-field-cyclic?noredirect=1&lq=1) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This rest on the following two facts about the ring  $\mathcal O $.
(i) All nonzero prime ideals in this ring  are also maximal ideals.
(2) For any ideal $I$ the quotient ring  $\mathcal O/I$ is a finite ring (the number of elements being called the norm of the ideal).

Now use this along with the following:
(3) For any finite field the nonzero elements form a cyclic group under multiplication. (A proof of this uses the property of Euler phi function)